# POST http://localhost:57722/api/Archivos 404 (Not Found)

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, ajax, asp.net-web-api, request

I am trying to upload 2gb files from an api with angularjs, using a post request from ajax, files that weigh 20 MB or less upload successfull, but when i try to upload a file that more weigh, the console,show me this message "POST http://localhost:57722/api/Archivos 404 (Not Found)"

i want to know, why happen this.

Comment: It will help if you can upload your API code and your angular code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asp.net limit the request size by default,you can modify your web.config, add blow configs:

```
<system.webServer>   
<security>   
    <requestFiltering>   
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />   
    </requestFiltering>   
</security>
```

```
<system.web>  
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483648" executionTimeout="20000"/>  
</system.web>
```